Issues with Customization Deployment in Copilot Studio Affecting Functionality and Default Prompts
I am currently facing an issue after adding my customization in Copilot Studio through Microsoft D365 F&O. I have added code that returns unposted journals by a specific date range (which will be provided by the user through Copilot Sidecar in the D365 F&O environment). After deploying my code, I am facing an issue where, upon opening the Copilot Sidecar, an error pops up.
enter image description here
Moreover, my previous customizations that worked fine before deploying are also not working. Additionally, the default prompts like "What can Copilot do?" sometimes respond with "Sorry, I don't know that one yet, but I'm always learning." Other times, they only respond after refreshing 4 to 5 times.
enter image description here
Is there any way to debug this via Visual Studio or through Copilot Studio?
